# The splitting field of a family of separable polynomials is Galois?

Tags: galois-theory, separable-extension

Let $I$ be a non empty set and $K$ a field. Let $\phi_i=\{f_i(x)\}_{i \in I}$ be a family of separable polynomials. Now, take $L:K$ be a extension given by $K$ and the roots of all polynomials in $\phi$. Prove that $L:K$ is separable and normal, then conclude that $L:K$ is Galois.

I've proved that $L:K$ is separable and normal, but I don't know how can I conclude that $L:K$ is Galois, cause I don't know if $[L:K]$ is finite. Can you have a tip?

Comment: It isn't finite in general. For instance, the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$ is the splitting field of all polynomials over $\mathbb Q$ (which are all separable), and its degree over $\mathbb Q$ is infinite. But that doesn't matter. Galois extensions are just normal and separable extensions, they are not necessarily finite.

Comment: Yeah. It sounds like you need to look up the definition of an infinite Galois extension. It is a bit tricky, and in the formulation of Galois correspondence a dash of topology is necessary. Like [in PlanetMath](https://www.planetmath.org/InfiniteGaloisTheory).

Comment: But there is no way to prove that $K = Inv_L(G(L/K))??$

Comment: Isn't separable + normal (+ algebraic) the definition of Galois?